# Which HTTP header is implemented when server sends same HTTP header multiple times with different values?

Tags: http, browser, https

I came across this one website made in PHP. `access-control-allow-origin` header is repeated thrice.
I want to know how is this response handled. Does the latter one hold more precedence than previous one or is it the other way around ? Or both hold equal significance ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general: all of them, comma-separated. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.3.2.2:

> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to the combined field value in order, separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value; a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when forwarding a message.